# How to execute solr zookeeper CLI to upload solr configuration

Tags: bash, scala, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

My scala app needs to interact with solr cloud via zookeeper.I need to upload the solr configuration files(conf folder) to the zookeeper. It is done using the following shell command :

```
 cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost zkHostAddress:2181 -d solr/collection/conf/ -n collection
```

I need this config upload to be done from my scala app itself and not use this shell command . How can I achieve this ?

Comment: SolrCloud clients already interact themselves transparently with zookeeper. Why don't you use a java client embedded in your scala app, like Solrj ?

Comment: I would really like to use solrj but i don't see any function call in the api which uploads the configurations.

Comment: So, certainly misunderstood what you wanted to do. You want to update which kind of configurations via Zookeeper ? Cores adresses ? What does the zkcli.sh do ? Maybe you should have a look to zookeeper clients to embed in your app like [Netflix curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator)?

Comment: So let me clarify it better. As far as I know the zkcli.sh takes all the parameters and uploads the solr conf folder contents(that also includes schema.xml) by **sending a request to zookeeper host(which is provided as parameter)** and the remote zookeeper inturn takes care of creating the same core configuration on solrcloud.Since my scala app is creating the conf folder and its content locally how do  I upload the configuration .

Comment: I had to reverse engineer the apache solr libraries to find out how it should be done:

#1 Requires "org.apache.solr" % "solr-core" % "4.3.1" in sbt
#2 The zkcli.sh passes the command-line arguments to ZkCLI.java.

#3 I extracted the code snippet & used directly in scala app
`val zkServerAdd : String = zkHost
          var zkClient :SolrZkClient  = null;
          try {
            zkClient = new SolrZkClient(zkServerAdd,30000,30000,new OnReconnect() {
              override def command() {}
            })
          }
          ZkController.uploadConfigDir(zkClient, new File(confdir), core)`

Comment: @Harsh Gupta. Would you be so kind to make an answer from your own comment? It seems as if you managed to do this trick, but unfortunatelly I can't figure out from your comment what exactly you did.

Answer (score 0):

Netflix wrote a good Zookeeper library called [Curator](http://curator.apache.org/) (now an Apache project) that works quite well from Scala e.g the following code establishes a connection to ZooKeeper

```
private def getConnection(connection : String): Option[CuratorFramework] = {
   val retryPolicy = new ExponentialBackoffRetry(100,3)
    val newConn = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder().
      connectString(connection).
      retryPolicy(retryPolicy).connectionTimeoutMs(1000).
      build
    try {
    newConn.start()
    newConn.checkExists.forPath(SOME_PATH)

    Some(newConn)
    } catch {
      case e:Exception => {
        error(e)
        None
      }
    }
}
```